# Cartopy mixing projections and overplotting image data

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm trying to overplot some satellite image data on top of a OSM tile.

I can plot them both separately but can't seem to overplot and I think it's down to the projection.

I load the data and get the projection information

```
ds = gdal.Open(fname)
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj = ds.GetProjection()

data=data.astype(np.float64)
projcs = inproj.GetAuthorityCode('PROJCS')
projection = ccrs.epsg(projcs)
```

The projection is

```
_EPSGProjection(32611)
```

I then set up the plot

```
subplot_kw = dict(projection=projection)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6), subplot_kw=subplot_kw)
```

Then get the OSM tile, set up the axes and add it

```
imagery = OSM()
ax = plt.axes(projection=imagery.crs)
ax.add_image(imagery, 14)
```

Finally I set the extent of the imagery data and add it with imshow

```
extent = (gt[0], gt[0] + ds.RasterXSize * gt[1],
          gt[3] + ds.RasterYSize * gt[5], gt[3])

img=ax.imshow(data, extent=extent, origin='upper', cmap='jet', vmin=1, vmax=1.3, alpha=0.1, transform=imagery.crs)
```

This doesn't display the imagery data at all, just the OSM tile.

I think the problem is with the transform keyword but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, and not runnable. Leading to less chance to get good answer or interest.

Comment: Given I can't redistribute the data due to it's license, there's not an easy way to give a runnable example. I'm hoping someone familiar with Cartopy will be above to point out how to set the projection correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the transform argument should be the coordinate system the data you are plotting are represented in. It is not related to the projection you want to visualise on. You are using the OSM coordinate system as the transform for your image data, this is wrong. You should be using the projection you defined for the image via the epsg code.